# Problema con script de linux hacia telegram

Tags: script, shell-script, telegram

Tengo el siguiente script, sencillo para enviar desde linux mensajes hacia Telegram:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERID="XXXXXXXXXX"
KEY="ZZZZZZZZZ:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"
MSG="Mensaje de Prueba"
curl -s --max-time 10 -d "chat_id=$USERID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$MSG" $URL
```

El programa no me da error, pero no me llegan los mensajes desde los servidores, estoy empezando en el mundo de los scripts, espero sepan comprender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es muy interesante utilizar la API de Telegram para monitorizar procesos en Linux y cuanta cosa se nos ocurra.

En tu script estas utilizando el metodo `sendMessage` para enviar mensajes en texto pero lo estas utilizando de una manera incorrecta, estas omitiendo la variable `chat_id` y `text`

Metodo correcto:

```
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage?chat_id=$USERID&text=$1"
```

Metodo incorrecto:

```
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"
```

Le hice algunas modificaciones a tu script para que tengas un Log donde puedas consultar el error que te devuelve la API en caso de no poder enviar el mensaje.

De esta forma te deberia servir el script, por supuesto sustituyendo lo que seria el **USERID** y **KEY**:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERID="-100XXXXXXXXXX" #Chat al que queremos enviar el mensaje.
KEY="ZZZZZZZZZ:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" #API Key generada por BotFather.
TIMEOUT="10" #Timeout de la petición a la API.
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage?chat_id=$USERID&text=$1" #URL de la API para enviar mensajes.
LOG="envio_telegram_`date "+%d%m%Y"`.log" #Log de envío de mensajes.
SONIDO=0 #Cuando SONIDO es 0, suena notificación, si es 1, es silenciosa.
FECHA_EJEC="$(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S")" #Generamos fecha y hora de ejecución
TEXTO="<b>$FECHA_EJEC:</b>\n<pre>$1</pre>" #Texto a enviar. Fecha de ejecución y primer parámetro del script.

curl -s --max-time $TIMEOUT -d "parse_mode=HTML&disable_notification=$SONIDO&chat_id=$USERID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=`echo -e $

"echo" >> $LOG #Introducimos línea nueva en el log.
```

Para utilizar el script es tan sencillo ejecutarlo de la siguiente manera pasandole un parametro que seria en este caso el texto a enviar:

```
./telegram_msg.sh "Prueba"
```

Te dejo este [enlace](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) con la informacion oficial de la API

Este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858927/how-to-obtain-the-chat-id-of-a-private-telegram-channel) de SO en inglés te muestra como conseguir el `chat_id` si no lo conoces